# Grunt - how to watch and synchronize files' deletion

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am a new user of Grunt. Currently I have a folder `static_src/img` that contains image source files (.psd) and image files (.png, .jpg, etc.). This folder is not public. Instead, I want to sync the change of only image files to another public folder `static/img`.

The problem is - it works well when I add/change a image file in `static_src/img`, but I don't know how to sync the change when I delete a file. Grunt-contrib-watch can detect the deletion in `static_src/img`, but I don't know how to delete the file in `static/img`. I tried grunt-contrib-clean, but it seems not work for me, maybe I used it not properly.

My Gruntfile.js is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
      dev: {
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: 'static_src/img/', src:['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], dest: 'static/img/'}
        ]
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dev: {
        src: ['static_src/img/**/*.png']
      }
    },
    watch: {
      copy: {
        files: ['static_src/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['copy'],
        options: {
          event: ['added', 'changed'],
        }
      },
      remove: {
        files: ['static_src/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['clean'],
        options: {
          event: ['deleted']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

So how to delete a specific file in a grunt-contrib-watch task? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For deleted event, you can delete all files in static/img and copy remaining files in static_src/img to static/img.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
      dev: {
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: 'static_src/img/', src:['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], dest: 'static/img/'}
        ]
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dev: {
        src: ['static/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}']    // Changed this from static_src to static
      }
    },
    watch: {
      copy: {
        files: ['static_src/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['copy'],
        options: {
          event: ['added', 'changed'],
        }
      },
      remove: {
        files: ['static_src/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['clean', 'copy'],    // Added copy task after clean
        options: {
          event: ['deleted']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

I guess this might be different from what you expected to delete a specific file, but works as expected.

Comment: Although this solution seems a little inefficient, I still apply it in my project. Because: 1. Efficiency is not very important for the development of a small project. 2. This method seems more modular. For now I don't want to call grunt api directly. It helps, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Grunt has a [file API](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) that you can leverage with events, so you can write a delete function that runs when a given watched file is deleted:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  if (action === 'deleted') {
    grunt.file.delete(fileToDelete);
  } 
});
```

The filepath is passed in, so you can do something like a regex to get the file name and prepend it with the appropriate path (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using nodejs' `watch` wrapper, which seems more stable (in Dec 2013) and versatile than native `fs.watch` / `fs.watchFile`.

https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Tasty thing is also its API:

```
  .on('add'
  .on('addDir'
  .on('change'
  .on('unlink'
  .on('unlinkDir'
  .on('error'
```

My rough benchmarks don't show performance problems when using this module.

Of course it's not a finished answer to your question, but a tip. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I made a task for this:

https://github.com/taylorcode/grunt-delete-sync

Hope this helps. Beware of destructive nature.

Answer (score 0):

Try out my [duplicate](https://github.com/vilic/duplicate), which may fit your needs.

It will delete the dest file if the source is deleted, and also it will delete empty folders after delete its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Using [grunt-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rsync) instead of the copy task, you can synchronize the deletion of files by using the [delete option](https://github.com/jedrichards/rsyncwrapper#exclamation-delete-boolean-default-false).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone landing here in 2016 or later, there is now a grunt-sync task which handles complete synchronization, including deleting files:
https://github.com/tomusdrw/grunt-sync